# How to convert code in a Vue div tag with :class to React code?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js

I am working to move some code over from Vue to React and stuck on this. Unfamiliar with :class and v-if syntex and wondering how it would be done in React

```
<div class="home_chart" :class="{'a': cat === 'a', 'b': cat === 'b'}">
    <i v-if="cat === 'a'" class="material-icons">
        icon_a
    </i>
    <i v-else-if="cat === 'b'" class="material-icons">
        icon_b
    </i>
    <div v-else class="blank">
        <span>name</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `className={<<logic>>}`

Comment: I don't know react but if it helps `:class="{'a': cat === 'a', 'b': cat === 'b'}"` means if cat equals 'a' then the class `a` will be added to the element i.e `<div class="home_chart a">` same for the `b`. The v-if just means - add this element to the DOM if this v-if is truthy.